Trouble merging TIFF files
I have several .tif files I need to merge. I've tried some methods but none of them work.
First I warped them all into the same crs (they were originally a 32617 and I reprojected them to the same crs). Then I tried to combine into a virtual raster. For some reason only two TIFFs got merged, the other two were missing.
I then tried to merge the two missing (Merged A) together and the two showing together (Merged B), which worked. But when I tried to merge these two new files, I only saw the result of Merged A.
I don't know why its doing this

Please tell us something about the tiffs gdalinfo output for one of the good ones and one of the bad ones.

Do they all show up in the expected location when loaded into QGIS individually?

They show up at the expected location individually and in Merged A and B

In regards to the info output, one bad file has a size of 6698, 10496: Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (664430.000000000000000,4884860.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (10.000000000000000,-10.000000000000000)
For a good one size is 6698, 4876:
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (664430.000000000000000,4933620.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (10.000000000000000,-10.000000000000000)
If there's something more I can provide, please let me know. Both are in ESGS 32617

I, too, have experienced the same issue - both with QGIS and Arc.  My solution is to merge first, then reproject.  This has worked for me, either when creating a virtual raster, or when creating a new, separate output raster.
